# Aligning formula problem

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
y ={}& \frac{1}{n!} \left\lbrace \int + f(a) \right. \\
     &\left. \vphantom{\int} + [h(u)+\phi(x)] + C \right\rbrace 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

How to align the plus sign with fraction? Thanks.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site please provide a full minimal example, then it is a lot easier for other to test your code. (3) Drop the use of `\left...\right` and use the manual ones instead (`\big\Big\bigg\Bigg`), then the alignment can be placed inside the construction and aligning on the `+` is easy.

Comment: Thank you.If I must use the left/right pair, how to modify the code?

Comment: Sorry to ask so naively, but are you sure you want to type `\int +` in this combination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alignment is not really necessary and `multline` might do the job. If you feel that alignment is important, here are three proposals.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The following aligns the + with the fraction
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
y ={} & \frac{1}{n!} \biggl\lbrace \int + f(a) \\
      & {} + [h(u)+\phi(x)] + C \biggr\rbrace
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
but with a slight offset; with the following the
offset is removed
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
y ={} & \frac{1}{n!} \biggl\lbrace \int + f(a) \\
      & {\mspace{-\medmuskip}} + [h(u)+\phi(x)] + C \biggr\rbrace
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
However, I'd align with the integral sign 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
y = \frac{1}{n!} \biggl\lbrace &\!\int + f(a) \\
      & {\mspace{-\medmuskip}} + [h(u)+\phi(x)] + C \biggr\rbrace
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. If I must use the left/right pair, how to modify the code?

Comment: @August As you were doing, with `\vphantom`.

Comment: Does “\mspace{-\medmuskip}” similar to “\!”, add some negative offset? I have used “\!” achieve the same result, it’s manual method.

Comment: @August `\!` adds `\mspace{-\thinmuskip}`, but a `\medmuskip` is added in front of a binary operation symbol and it is larger than `\thinmuskip`.

Comment: Your method is also worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
\begin{align*}
y &= \frac{1}{n!} \left\lbrace \int + f(a) \right. \\
  &\phantom{=} \left. \vphantom{\int} + [h(u)+\phi(x)] + C \right\rbrace 
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Thank you. The plus sign wasn’t aligning with fraction .

Answer (score 3):

You do not require alignment here (which is why you are needing `\phantom` etc to hide the alignment point) you just have a line that needs to be broken (so I  assume you have a narrow text width) something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
y =\frac{1}{n!} \Bigl\lbrace \int + f(a)  \\
    {} + [h(u)+\phi(x)] + C \Bigr\rbrace 
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I use vphantom to keep same sized big left/right brace.If I must use the left/right pair, how to modify the code?

Comment: you can still use \left . with the vphantom if you wish (but usually using `\Bigl` (for some fixed name size is better) that change is separate from teh suggestion to change align to multline